# Google maps v 3 & GWT wrapper

Tags: google-maps, gwt, uibuilder

I am supposed to do a project that uses google maps api v3  to create a path( like a road ) using GWT google Map wrapper .

I am just starting both of these and would like some one to show me such basic functionality in codes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/wiki/GettingStarted